# How to disable a button while processing

Tags: java, javafx

How can I disable a JavaFX button while something is processing (to prevent user from spamming the button)?

```
primaryStage.setTitle("Update Stuff");

Label lbl = new Label();
lbl.setText("Nothing here yet");

Button btn = new Button();
btn.setText("Update");
btn.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {

    @Override
    public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
        btn.setDisable(true); //I tried this, but to no avail
        lbl.setText(getNumberOfViewers()); // this might take a few seconds, need to disable button during this time
        btn.setDisable(false);
    }
});

VBox root = new VBox();
root.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
root.getChildren().addAll(btn, lbl);
primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 200, 100));
primaryStage.show();
```

Comment: You should avoid blocking the UI thread at all! Have a look at http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/interoperability-tutorial/concurrency.htm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based off of your code you posted, it would be something like this in javafx 8:

```
primaryStage.setTitle("Update Stuff");

Label lbl = new Label();
lbl.setText("Nothing here yet");

Button btn = new Button();
btn.setText("Update");
btn.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {

    @Override
    public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
        btn.setDisable(true);
        new Thread(()->{
            final String numberOfViews =  getNumberOfViewers();
            Platform.runLater(()->{
                lbl.setText(numberOfViews);
                btn.setDisable(false);
            });                   
        }).start();
        lbl.setText(getNumberOfViewers()); // this might take a few seconds, need to disable button during this time
    }
});

VBox root = new VBox();
root.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
root.getChildren().addAll(btn, lbl);
primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 200, 100));
primaryStage.show();
```

The new thread will make it so that the UI thread is never actually blocked (and windows doesn't give you that nasty 'the application has stopped responding' business), and then inside the thread, anytime you want to change something on the GUI, use the Platform.runLater() syntax, technically you are making a new 'Runnable' object inside of the runLater method, but thanks to lambda expressions, you don't need to worry about that! If you don't use the `Platform.runLater()` you'll get a 'not on the Javafx application Thread' exception when you try to update stuff.

Also worth noting, I think in javafx 2.* (java 7) it's `btn.setEnable(false)` instead of `btn.setDisable(true)` just a change of how they went about it. same effect.

Answer (score 0):

use the f.f.g code

```
btn.setEnabled(false);
```

within the handle method, then after:

```
btn.setEnabled(true);
```

Comment: I'm sorry, but my in my previous comment I said that JavaFX buttons didn't have a `setEnabled()` method, which is not true for JavaFX 7. I am using JavaFX 8, where this method is called `setDisable()`.  However, I have already tried the code you proposed, and it didn't work. I think WillBD (in the accepted answer) give a good explanation to this. Thanks for your input anyway!